# What is replacement of ajax call to load an html page in offline mode?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm navigating to an HTML page by the below code. this code works fine in the online mode (when I have internet), but it doesn't work in offline mode when there is no network connectivity.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var homeUrl = "./js/app/views/abc.html";
        $.ajax({
            url: homeUrl, success: function (result) {
                $('#myapp').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I thought to fix it by the below code, but I don't think its good solution, because I need to write whole HTML content as a string, so this is error-prone, complex and cannot be done easily for multiple pages. Is there any better way to do it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var result = "Whole html content of abc.html";
        $('#myapp').html(result);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i think you are talking about `service workers` ?

Comment: I don't know what is that

Comment: Have a look, official docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: Also research PWA (progressive web app)

Comment: And offline-first stuff like [Hoodie](http://hood.ie/)

Comment: in offline mode you need API previous data, you will have to work with google workbox

Comment: Depends a bit on what other script you're running. If this main page only reroutes to abc.html, I would just save abc.html and the other pages to local and go from there. Do you have more information about if abc.html can run on its own or does it also rely on ajax calls to regenerate its state? As a sidenote,I don't see the relevance of service workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried storing it in localStorage? Basically, whenever you get call that endpoint, you save it's result in localStorage.

Then, when your browser is offline is your server calls returns an error, you grab the stored result from localStorage and render the page with it.

```js
var homeUrl = "./js/app/views/abc.html";
var cacheKey = 'myUniqueCacheKey';
$.ajax({
  url: homeUrl,
  success: function (result) {
    localStorage.setItem(cacheKey, String(result));
    $('#myapp').html(result);
  },
  error: function (err) {
    var htmlString = localStorage.getItem(cacheKey);

    if (err.condition && htmlString) {
      $('#myapp').html(htmlString);
    } else {
      // do your normal error handling here
    }
  }
});
```

MDN: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: what is the internet is not available at the first time?

Comment: If the internet is not available the first time, the user’s browser cannot connect to your server to fetch the source code files that define your website, including the above code. Unless you plan on installing the source code on the user’s computer manually, you are asking to solve an impossible problem.